# Не срабатывает хендлер на удаление сообщений в юзерботе Телеграм на pyrogram python

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Суть задачи - отслеживать удаление сообщения и определять, какой пользователь удалил сообщение (либо в личке, либо в групповом чате), в личке почему то не получается словить хендлер. Пробовал filters.user - не срабатывает хендлер. А в групповом чате срабатывает хендлер но не выполняет команду и выдаёт вот такую ошибку (ниже)

Подскажите, что не так написал или как написать хендлер, отслеживающий удаление сообщения в конкретном приватном чате?

Код хендлера:

```
@app.on_deleted_messages(filters.chat(-100145451746))
def func(_, message):
    app.send_message(chat_id='me', text=f'{message.from_user.id} Удалено')
```

Код ошибки:

```
'List' object has no attribute 'from_user'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\naeni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 219, in handler_worker
    await self.loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\naeni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Projects\Helper\app.py", line 22, in funcs
    app.send_message(chat_id='me', text=f'{message.from_user.id} Удалено')
AttributeError: 'List' object has no attribute 'from_user'enter code here
```

Comment: посмотри свою переменную `message`, возможно, что бы получить `from_user.id` нужно по другому достать айди

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция, которая оборачивается в декоратор `@app.on_deleted_messages` принимает список из сообщений, а не одно сообщение, как прочие декораторы.

`client (Client)` – The Client itself, useful when you want to call other API methods inside the message handler.
messages (List of Message) – The deleted messages, as list.